# javascript regex two types of delimiters capture as one group

Tags: javascript, regex

Excuse me if i did some mistakes while posting my first question here.

I had a problem while i was working with javascript lodash template.
I was trying to rewrite regex for evaluate delimiter so it could accept two types of delimiter and capture it as one group.

First i tried two do two groups

```
/<%([\s\S]+?)%>|{{([\s\S]+?)}}/
```

but i end up getting two groups, then i tried

```
/(?:<%|{{)([\s\S]+?)(?:%>|}})/
```

It worked and captured two groups as one but it worked for some cases that shouldn't work 
For example:

```
<% 
  text1 
%>  //should work
{{ text2 }}  //should work
<% text2 }}  // shouldn't work
```

Is there is a way to match by several delimiters but capture only one group?

Comment: something similar could be done with backreference(something like `(['"])[^'"]+\1`). but since closing delimiter differs from opening one I believe it is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with lookaheads:

```js
const regex = /(?:<%(?=.*%>)|{{(?=.*}}))(.+)(?:}}|%>)/

console.log(regex.test('<% Hello World %>')) // true
console.log(regex.test('{{ Hello World }}')) // true
console.log(regex.test('<% Hello World }}')) // false
console.log(regex.test('{{ Hello World %>')) // false
```

[Try it on regex101.com!](https://regex101.com/r/m8EIzO/3)

Comment: Looks like it find matches, but unfortunately it doesn't capture a group. Thanks, i guess i need to study advanced lookaheads

Comment: @danziamo I added a capturing group around `.+`, which should capture the content between the delimiters as the first group.

Comment: Almost works, but one thing left, that would be very helpful to fix.
It captures one group but delimiters are included inside, is it possible to capture text without delimiters inside?

Comment: Updated the regex once more. The closing delimiters should now be explicitly excluded as well.

Comment: One last thing. If it is not difficult. Can you do your magic to match this cases, tried to use [\s\S] but failed:
[https://regex101.com/r/wi8tNE/1](https://regex101.com/r/wi8tNE/1)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use lookaheads:

```
(?:<%(?=[^<>]*%>)|{{(?=[^{}]*}}))(.+?)(?:%>|}})
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/IXNYdB/1)

Comment: Thank you for response. There is a problem for case
<% text 2 }} {{ text 3 %>

Answer (score 0):

Another maybe a bit simpler alternative:

```js
var l = console.log, r = /<%.+?%>|{{.+?}}/, f = s => (s.match(r) + '').slice(2, -2)

l( f('<% a %>') ) // " a "
l( f('{{ b }}') ) // " b "
l( f('<% c }}') ) // ""
l( f('{{ d %>') ) // ""
```

The repeating pattern can also be replaced, but that might be a bit of overkill:

```js
var l = console.log, r = new RegExp( '<%1%>|{{1}}'.split(1).join`([\\s\\S]+?)` ), m

f = s => (m = s.match(r)) ? m[1] || m[2] : ''

l( r )            // /<%([\s\S]+?)%>|{{([\s\S]+?)}}/
l( f('<% a %>') ) // " a "
l( f('{{ b }}') ) // " b "
l( f('<% c }}') ) // ""
l( f('{{ d %>') ) // ""
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but i needed to capture text between delimiters as well. And captured text between different types of delimiters should be considered as one group, and in this example i am afraid it returns two captured groups